# When routing , component is not rendering in Side page

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router

This the js file where I have added my router and it contains all the route of my application
router.  Below is the code of My App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Layout />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/employee' exact component={Employee} />
                    <Route path='/employer' component={Employer} />
                    <Route path='/addEmployer' component={AddEmployer} />
                    <Route path='/user' component={UserManagement} />
                    <Route path='/addUser' component={AddUser} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

I have created the Layout page which contains my navbar component, sidebar component, main content and footer too.
Below is the code of Layout.js. I want my layout to be static across the application

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import '../../css/main.css';

import { Navbar } from './Navbar';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import { SideNavbar } from './SideNavbar';

export class Layout extends Component {
    static displayName = Layout.name;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <div id="layoutSidenav">
                    <SideNavbar />
                    <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                        <main className="flex">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </main>
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I am routing the employer from url, the employer component is not rendering under main folder.
currently it is been rendering under the footer of the page. This causing an issue in makin my application as SPA.

Awaiting the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your `Layout` component looks to be designed to render the content as `children`, but in your `App` component you don't pass it any children. The `Switch` is rendered under/after `Layout` component.

```
class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
          <SideNavbar />
          <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
            <main className="flex">
              {this.props.children} // <-- content
            </main>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Layout /> // <-- no children
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/employee' exact component={Employee} />
          <Route path='/employer' component={Employer} />
          <Route path='/addEmployer' component={AddEmployer} />
          <Route path='/user' component={UserManagement} />
          <Route path='/addUser' component={AddUser} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

## Solution

Wrap the `Switch`.

```
class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/employee' exact component={Employee} />
            <Route path='/employer' component={Employer} />
            <Route path='/addEmployer' component={AddEmployer} />
            <Route path='/user' component={UserManagement} />
            <Route path='/addUser' component={AddUser} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Router needs to define where we wanted to render our component. Like In my case it should be under Layout component itself rather the defining at App.js part